# Avoid writing code twice while maintaining proper way to code?

Tags: optimization, file-io, input, lua

I'm trying to create a function `getInput(prompt, number)`, where `prompt` is the text that will get printed in front of user's input (e.g. `>` or `Choose a password:`) and `number` is a boolean value which tells whether the input should be a number or any type.

Here's the function I wrote:

```
function getInput(prompt, number)
    if number then
        while not input do
            io.write(prompt)
            input = tonumber(io.read())
        end
    else
        io.write(prompt)
        input = io.read()
    end
    return input
end
```

However, I'm repeating the code quite alot.
I have `io.write(prompt)` written twice and I also have `input = io.read()` twice with `tonumber()` around one of the calls.
I'm basically just repeating the same thing twice, once in a `while` loop and once not in it.

Here's a little workaround I made:

```
function getInput(prompt, number)
    while not input do
        io.write(prompt)
        input = io.read()
        if number then
            input = tonumber(input)
        end
    end
    return input
end
```

This version only has `io.write()` and `io.read()` written once, but it's not that "proper" code.
I'm using a `while` loop even if there's no need to (when `number` is false).
I'm also doing the `if number` check on every round of the `while` loop (when `number` is true).

Should I go with the first code, or is there a way to improve the second code to be more "proper" ?

Comment: The second version loops forever when it reaches EOF.

Comment: `input` is global and its value preserves from previous call, so both functions would not ask user to enter data on the second call.

Comment: Also consider `read("*n")` to read a number. then your code paths aren't even the same.

Comment: @daurnimator - `read'*n'` doesn't allow distinguishing between EOF and non-numeric string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, repeating a very simple, single-line piece of code similar to `io.write(prompt)` is not perceived "code duplication". Moreover, repeatedly checking the same simple condition is not generally perceived a performance hazard. Both ways are equally readable, so either one is fine, depending on your preference.

One possible improvement would be splitting the function in two, and dropping the `number` flag, like this:

```
function getInput(prompt)
    io.write(prompt)
    return io.read()
end
function getNumericInput(prompt)
    while not input do
        io.write(prompt)
        input = tonumber(io.read())
    end
    return input
end
```

However, this may not be acceptable in situations when the type of input is decided at runtime, and must be controlled through a variable.

Comment: Well I won't have this problem, and besides you can only write text and/or numbers, so this will be enough! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
local function getInput(prompt, number)
   io.write(prompt)
   local input = (number and tonumber or assert)((assert(io.read(), 'EOF')))
   return (input and function() return input end or getInput)(prompt, number)
end
```

Comment: This is not a tail call and can potentially overflow the call stack.

Comment: @lhf - Fixed to make a tail call  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'd say that the first form is pretty clear and easy to read. There's very little wrong with it, even though you're writing pretty similar statements twice.

The only suggestions I'd have would be to split it into two functions without the boolean flag (i.e., getInput(prompt) and getNumericInput(prompt)), or to change the boolean to a type and move the logic for capturing the proper type to a separate method:

```
function getInput(prompt, type)
    io.write(prompt)
       input = getTypedInput(type)
    return input
end

function getTypedInput(type)
    input(io.read())
    ...change to type here <I don't know lua syntax)
    return input
end
```

The latter is probably overkill for the problem you have, unless you think there's a chance you're going to use more types than numeric or non-numeric.